# How does IPFS public gateways (like ipfs.io) get contents of simple IPFS nodes?

Tags: distributed-system, ipfs

Using my `IPFS` node, I uploaded files to the network which became accessible via `ipfs.io` HTTP requests. After a few days I noticed that these files are no more accessible.

I know that this is due to garbage collection, but my questions are:

1. Does `IPFS` public gateways retrieve data **automatically** from `ipfs` nodes?
2. How much time it takes to get the content disappeared?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found an answer to my question:

> Does IPFS public gateways retrieve data automatically from ipfs nodes?

When a file is requested from a node, the public gateway forward it from the nearest node hosting the file and cache it for futur requests. That's why the file become accessible through the public gateway.

> How much time it takes to get the content disappeared?

It depends on the cache-control policy of the public gateway.

Answer (score 0):

> Does IPFS public gateways retrieve data automatically from ipfs nodes?

No, they will fetch from the nodes that have the content during initial request and while fetching the data there are chances that they will be stored in other nodes as well. More in depth explanation can be found here: https://github.com/ipfs/faq/issues/48#issuecomment-152917088

> How much time it takes to get the content disappeared?

As long as the network have atleast one node with that content it's still alive. IPFS daemon allows you to change the GC duration manually. So, you can't really determine the time. If you need your content to be stored permanently, you can pin that file across multiple nodes.